# Two TextWatchers creating an infinite loop

Tags: android, textwatcher

I have 3 EditText fields in my android app that I'm trying to have communicate with each other. They are order total, amount received, and tip. The user enters the price of the order in the first EditText. The other two EditTexts are the ones I'm wanting to modify based on the value of each one. If the user enters 20.00 in the order total and 25.00 in the amount received, I would like the tip to display 5.00. Likewise, if they enter 20.00 in the order total, and 5.00 in the tip, I would like amount received to display 25.00. I have all the calculations correct, and each one of my TextWatchers work as long as the other one is commented out, but with both of them it just creates an infinite loop. Is there a good way to do this, or can someone please point me in the right direction to some helpful links? I can't seem to find any that work for what I'm trying to do.

My code is as follows:

```
eTotalCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.orderTotal);
eAmountReceived = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountReceived);
eTip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tip);
eMileage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mileage);
eGrandTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grandTotal);

eAmountReceived.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after){}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count){}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        eAmountReceived = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountReceived);
        eTotalCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.orderTotal);
        eTip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tip);
        eMileage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mileage);
        eGrandTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grandTotal);

        sAmountReceived = eAmountReceived.getText().toString();
        sTotalCost = eTotalCost.getText().toString();
        sMileage = eMileage.getText().toString();
        sTip = eTip.getText().toString();

        try
        {
            dAmountReceived = Double.parseDouble(sAmountReceived);
            dTotalCost = Double.parseDouble(sTotalCost);

            dSubtract = dAmountReceived - dTotalCost;
            dMileage = Double.parseDouble(sMileage);
            dGrandTotal = dSubtract + dMileage;
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){}

        sTip = String.valueOf(dSubtract);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        sTip = df.format(dSubtract);

        eTip.setText(sTip);

        sGrandTotal = String.valueOf(dGrandTotal);
        sGrandTotal = df.format(dGrandTotal);
        eGrandTotal.setText(sGrandTotal);
    }
});


eTip.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after){}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count){}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        eAmountReceived = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amountReceived);
        eTotalCost = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.orderTotal);
        eTip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tip);
        eMileage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mileage);
        eGrandTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grandTotal);

        sAmountReceived = eAmountReceived.getText().toString();
        sTotalCost = eTotalCost.getText().toString();
        sMileage = eMileage.getText().toString();
        sTip = eTip.getText().toString();

        try 
        {
            dTip = Double.parseDouble(sTip);
            dTotalCost = Double.parseDouble(sTotalCost);

            dAdd = dTotalCost + dTip;
            dMileage = Double.parseDouble(sMileage);
            dGrandTotal = dTip + dMileage;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}

        sAmountReceived = String.valueOf(dAdd);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        sAmountReceived = df.format(dAdd);

        eAmountReceived.setText(sAmountReceived);

        sGrandTotal = String.valueOf(dGrandTotal);
        sGrandTotal = df.format(dGrandTotal);
        eGrandTotal.setText(sGrandTotal);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looping setText methods from withing afterTextChanged callback

What is going on:

You have 2 textWatchers: one for `eTip` and one for `eAmountReceived`

When you call `setText()` on any of those fields it will start looping, since setText will trigger `afterTextChanged` and in both of your text watchers you are calling `setText()` for opposite field which, again, will trigger `afterTextChanged`

In order to avoid this, introduce some boolean flags that will indicate is value already set for respective edittext or call setText only if new value is different from previous one which is already set

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Boolean flags yet. I made an isSet() function and thought I was on the right track with it but I guess not. However, I did get it to work by doing if (getCurrentFocus() == myEditText) in each afterTextChanged.

Answer (score 2):

First of all delete findviewbyid codes in afterTextChanged. You don't need to to declare them in every usage. Only use is in onCreate.

The easiest solution for your question keep your TextWatchers in variables declared in class. Then before every setText() call, call removeTextChangeListener for all textWatchers and re add textWatchers after setText().

Edit: not remove and re add in all setText() call. Do it only in condition makes loop.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem when trying to create a currency converter app. (Change value in editText 1 should change the value in editText 2 and vice versa).

The way I got around it was to create two text watchers.

```
private TextWatcher TextWatcherClass = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        editText2.removeTextChangedListener(TextWatcherClass2);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        editText2.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcherClass2);
    }

};

private TextWatcher TextWatcherClass2 = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        editText1.removeTextChangedListener(TextWatcherClass);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                  int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        editText1.addTextChangedListener(TextWatcherClass);
    }

};
```

Hope this helps.